# Looking for the proper way to format the text in a column and compare that with the value of a cell?

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to format the information from a column that I am querying and compare that to information in a cell. I have tried to hack together various ways to do this, but I am not a proficient SQL/spreadsheet user.

In `COLUMN I` there is nothing.
In `COLUMN K` there is a match on `A2`.
In `COLUMN N` there is Information formatted like `31'-40'` and `41'+`.

I would prefer to use `=` instead of `contains`.

The `REPLACE` Function seems to work when I substitute `N` for a String and run it on the W3 School Website.

The `REGEXREPLACE` seems to work on `D2`. I would expect them to match, but they do not.

```
COUNT( QUERY( '2019'!A2:P, "select D where I='' and upper(K) contains '" & UPPER(A2) & "' and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N, '-', ''), '''', ''), '+','') contains '"& Regexreplace(D2,"[[:punct:]]","") &"' ")
```

I get `0` matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost had it, but try like this:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(2019!D2:D, I2:I="", 
                          REGEXMATCH(UPPER(K2:K), UPPER(A2)), 
                          REGEXMATCH(UPPER(N2:N), UPPER(D2))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sorry, It took me so long to accept or respond. I appreciate the help, immensely. For some reason using the LEFT() function on D2 so that I only had the first digit worked for me as a work around. I don't understand it at all. I feel like it didn't like the punctuation. But I'm going to go back and implement this as it is a proper solution. Thanks again!